# Updating database bottle sqlite

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to make a little web app to manage a greenhouse, but I can't update my database.

I tried with a `GET` and a `POST` method but nothing happened.

I don't have an error code or something, so I don't see where the problem is.

Below you can see the static page where I try to enter a number and update the database

Here is my Python app :

```
@route('/mtemp', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def temp_modification():


        if request.GET.get('save'):
              new_temp = request.GET.get('ntemp')
              new_temp = int(new_temp)
              conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
              c = conn.cursor()
              c.execute("UPDATE database SET temp = ?", (new_temp))
              conn.commit()

              redirect("/")
       else:
              conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
              c = conn.cursor()
              c.execute("SELECT temp FROM database")
              cur_data = c.fetchone()
              cur_data = str(cur_data)
              for char in b:
                    cur_data = cur_data.replace(char, "")


return template('modtemp', old=cur_data)


run(host = '0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

and my template :

```
<p>Nouvelle Température : </p>
<form action="/" method="GET">
<input type="number"  name="ntemp" value="{{old}}" >
<input type="submit" name"save" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: Ìt seems that the indentation of your `temp_modification` function is strange. Could you check it?

Comment: Is your table called `database`?

Comment: The indentation is good, upload problem i must correct that, and yes my table is called database

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if your code is actually being hit when the form is submitted? Your form action in the template is set to submit the form to "/", but your bottle code looks like it is set to "/mtemp". I wouldn't expect this code to work as is. You would need to change your form action to be "/mtemp".

Comment: the form is also set to make a GET request